# UIImagePickerController can not select picture

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I have some problem when i work with  UIImagePickerController .when I presentModalViewController,and the picker pops up right,but i can not select a picture! when i touch on the picture list, the list can only scroll up and down,but can not select!

how about this? thanks.

Comment: Do you understand how `UIImagePickerController` works? Do you have the delegate methods implemented?

Comment: sure,i have implemented the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol in the main view.the same code works well in my demo,but when i added this to my project,it goes worng.

Comment: I can take a picture,but when i press "use",the program freeze

Comment: Use the debugger and check the stack trace.

Comment: the code :

@interface PhotoPickerViewController : UIViewController <                                UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

....

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                             initWithRootViewController:photoPickerViewController ];
   [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

Comment: wow,the program got into the system library,how can i trace into?

Comment: There is no error message about stackoverflow shown in debug console,when press "cancle",i can also return to my main view.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.

I had the same problem, and was able to fix it by adding a

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

at the end of 
    `imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`

Example:

```
extension MyViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            // Do something with your image
            ...
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the docs provide this answer:

"5. When the user taps a button to pick a newly-captured or saved image or movie, or cancels the operation, dismiss the image picker using your delegate object. For newly-captured media, your delegate can then save it to the Camera Roll on the device. For previously-saved media, your delegate can then use the image data according to the purpose of your app."

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Answer (score 0):

You must implement the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```